# AJAX and JSP , $getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

So im really having difficulties in understanding the parameters of $.getJSON(), Im currently in my OJT, and there is a AJAX request parameter that I cant figure out.

```
$.getJSON(jspGetElems, {elem: $(this).val()}).done(function(result){
        //console.log('result',result);
    });
```

what does the " {elem: $(this).val()} " actually mean?

Comment: Its the `data` you are going to pass to the **server**.

Comment: but where did the " elem: " came from?

Comment: `elem` is kind of key name for you to identify in the server, that you are passing your value with this `key` name and you can get that value via `elem` key..

Comment: You can check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery.getJSON() has 3 parameter url,data and success. here, in your question **elem: $(this).val()** is data. You can pass multiple data to server like

```
{
  "one": "Singular sensation",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

Try example.

```
$.getJSON( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",{ userId: 1 } ) 
            .done(function(result){ console.log('result',result); });
```